# How to write multiple text files from one text

Tags: c#, forms, filestream

I have a text file like "ddd,aaa,bb,cccc,3". This text has one million line. I take all word in  arrays. for example

```
value1=ddd, value2=aaa , value3=bbb , value4=cccc, value5=3`.
```

It should be different algorithm but this is not important.

When read this text, it take last number `3` and repeat the first record three times because last number is 3. If last number should be 4, then it will repeat four times. And it gives new row number like that

```
1,aa,bb,ccc,ddd,3
2,aa,bb,ccc,ddd,3
3,aa,bb,ccc,ddd,3
```

now I want, when this row count is equals 10000 it have to be write new text. for example if my reading text has 50000 record, it have to write 5. text file. How Can I do that. Could you help me?

This is write method.

```
public void Save()
{
    value1.Remove("SE");
    value2.Remove("CS");
    value3.Remove("NAME");
    value4.Remove("SURNAME");
    value5.Remove("Number");

    int rowNum = 1;
    int maxNum = 1000;
    String aa = "";
    String TMPvalue;

         for (int d = 0; d < value5.Count; d++) 
         {      
             for (int m = 0; m < (Int32)value5[d]; m++,rowNum++)
             {
                 TMPvalue = rowNum + "," + value1[d] + "," + value2[d] + "," + value3[d] + "," + value4[d] + "," + "TEB";
                 aa = aa + TMPvalue + "\n";

                 if(rowNum==maxNum){
                    path = path + Convert.ToString(xnum) + ".txt";
                    file1 = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path);
                    aa = "ROWNUM,v1,v2,v3,v4" + "\n\r" + aa;
                    string[] lines = aa.Split('\n');
                    foreach (string s in lines)
                    {
                        file1.WriteLine(s);
                    }
                    file1.close();
                    rowNum=1;
                    aa = "";
                 }
             }
         }

         file2 = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path);
         aa = "ROWNUM,v1,v2,v3,v4" + "\n\r" + aa;
         string[] lines = aa.Split('\n');
         foreach (string s in lines)
         {
             file2.WriteLine(s);
         }
         file2.close()
  }
```

Comment: you need to close the old file and open the new file.  What is the mystery here?

Comment: when I added close and open file. It do not read write.

Comment: Wrap your `StreamWriter` inside a `using` block

Comment: When program run with debug ,if it in "if" condition it again goes for loop.So write so many file.

Comment: @19052013 maybe you should show us the code with the problem then.  This clearly does not close the file so it can't be correct. -1

Comment: @Hogan  Are you try it ? I try it. I do debug. but when it in if condition it goes again out of writing file2. if condition has file1 on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use following LINQ query which should do what you want:

```
var lines10kGroups = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Temp\File.txt")
    .Select(l => new { Line = l, Fields = l.Split(',') })
    .Where(x => x.Fields.Length > 1)
    .Select(x => new{ LastToken = x.Fields.Last().Trim().Split('=').Last(), x.Fields, x.Line})
    .Where(x => x.LastToken.All(Char.IsDigit))  // checks if all characters are digits, pre-check for int.Parse
    .Select(x => new { Count = int.Parse(x.LastToken), x.Line, x.Fields })
    .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Repeat(x.Line, x.Count)) // this repeats count-lines
    .Select((line, index) => new{ line, index })
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / 10000); // integer division trick to group by 10k lines

string targetDir = @"C:\Temp\TestDirectory";
Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDir);
int fileNum = 0;
foreach (var lineGroup in lines10kGroups)
{ 
    string path = Path.Combine(targetDir, string.Format("File_{0}.txt", ++fileNum));
    while(File.Exists(path))
        path = Path.Combine(targetDir, string.Format("File_{0}.txt", ++fileNum));
    File.WriteAllLines(path, lineGroup.Select(x => x.line));
}
```

Comment: code performance is important for me. And I have to change read algorithm for this code. I can not implement this code :((

Comment: @19052013: performance should be fine. I have tested it with a 5MB sample file which containes lines which ends with a number between 2 and 10(so repeating 2 to 10 lines for each line). It took only 32 seconds to create ~40k-files: `Duration: 00:00:32.0788782
Files: 39578
Total-Lines: 395772`

Comment: @19052013 - Why would you think this is slow?

Comment: thanks a lot, but I have to use arraylist on read code. It is format. I could not change..

Comment: Sorry, my performance test was based on my test-group-size (10 instead of 10k). Give me a minute, it should be even more efficient since less files have to be generated. **Edit**: this looks better, half a second: `Duration: 00:00:00.5746402
Files: 40
Total-Lines: 395772`

Comment: I think you've overwhelmed the OP with you Linq-fu.